# Using an Angular Directive to draw a Google Chart without manual bootstrapping

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I want to write a directive to draw a google chart but I want to do so **with out** using the **Angular-Google-Charts** library or **manually bootstrapping angular**. As this will sit on Google Apps Script and the chart is a much lesser element of the webpage, the chart takes much lower priority.

I was hoping that I could use the link function in the directive to load the google charts library and then draw the chart like so:

```
.directive('barChart', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A', 
    scope: {
        data: '=',
     },
     link: function(data, elm, attrs) {       
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
          data.addRows([
            ['Mushrooms', 3],
            ['Onions', 1],
            ['Olives', 1],
            ['Zucchini', 1],
            ['Pepperoni', 2]
          ]);
          var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                         'width':400,
                         'height':300};
          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(elm[0]);
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
     }
  };
}]);
```

Is making this approach work possible? If so, how?

Many thanks
Toby

Answer (score 0):

There's a directive already made for this. https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart/

Make sure you use the master branch, gh-pages branch is development and slightly unstable at the moment.

Comment: Oh. I read more carefully and noticed "Without angular-google-chart" after. So, why do you not want to use it? I'm one of the core contributors so I'd love to hear feedback from someone who doesn't like it.

Comment: What I'm working with at the moment is sat on Google Apps Script, meaning that all kinds of funny things end up happening and that I would like to build my understanding and ability of how these things work. I might end up taking a read of the angular google chart to see if I can understand what makes it tick.

Comment: The main thing that makes Angular-Google-Chart work without manually bootstrapping angular is the googleChartApiPromise service, which returns a promise to the directive that resolves when the charts API is loaded. Only after the API is loaded does it try to draw your chart. The service itself is responsible for adding a script tag to the document which loads the google loader, calls `google.load(...)` and then resolves the promise from the callback given to the google API.  When I first started working with the project, it took a long time to fully understand how it all worked.

Comment: The googleChartApiPromise service, when broken out into it's own file is about 50 lines.  There's probably about 20-30 lines of actual program logic and the rest is whitespace, curly braces, and angular dependency injection fluff.

Comment: The approach you're taking MAY work, but it would not be able to interact with angular data.  Your directive would need to operate in a state in which the charts API is not loaded. Then, when it is loaded it would have to either watch for changes in data or supply an interface of some kind to the outside world to change the chart data. I'm in the middle of a re-write on much of angular-google-chart to make it work either way, depending on how people want to work with it. If your directive makes any changes to data it needs to call $scope.$apply() as it is outside the digest loop.